# Missing line numbers from debug symbols for library in whole program, but not on its own

Tags: gdb, debug-symbols, libtool, dwarf

I'm seeing an odd issue when trying to use gdb to debug a test program for a package built with libtool. If I run `libtool --mode=execute gdb .libs/libfoo.so` and ask it to list the source of some function `list Bar::Baz`, I get the source code as expected. If I run `libtool --mode=execute gdb binary`, I can break in `Bar::Baz()`, and see its arguments in a stack trace, but I get no source file or line numbers, like so:

```
#7  0x018348e5 in Bar::Baz(Qux*, Quux*) () from /path/to/libfoo.so
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- debug symbols are present!
```

Similarly, if I try to `list Bar::Baz` when debugging the executable, I get

```
No line number known for 'Bar::Baz'.
```

I have confirmed that the binary is linked with `-g`, and I can list its `main` function, so I know some of the debug information is present are present.

When I say `info sources`, I get a full listing of the files from which the library is built, with correct absolute paths. When I say `info shared`, I get the correct path listed to the object file, with a `Yes` in the `Syms` column.

Any further ideas what could be going wrong, and how to fix it?

---

Edit 1: By accident, I ran `objdump -g` on the offending library, and got the following output:

```
/path/to/foo.so.0.0.0: file format elf32-i386
objdump: /path/to/foo.so.0.0.0: no recognized debugging information
```

This is surprising, since `objdump -h` (what I had tried to run) lists a bunch of `.debug_*` sections. The `objdump` manual suggests `readelf -w` as well, and that seems to print a huge pile of information. I need to go look through at what it actually provides, though.

---

Edit 2: So, `readelf -w` has produced some enlightenment. For whatever reason, the shared object file doesn't seem to contain the debugging information from <strike>the vast majority</strike> *any* of the objects linked into it. Based on the Makefiles, it's possible that the command that actually gathers up the objects into the shared library isn't passed `-g`, and so that information isn't properly propagated. The funny thing is that this works (has full debug information) on all our other configurations, including the same compiler version on x86_64 (versus the present x86).

---

Edit 3: Actually went through a full rebuild with the modified Makefile with -g added on the LDFLAGS, and it made no difference. Now I'm well and truly baffled.

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer to an old question, but your problem matched mine, but none of the solutions worked.  Here is what worked for me.

Change CFLAGS -g to "-g -gstabs".

objdump was not recognizing the dwarf style debug information.  -gstabs changes this format to one that works with objdump -g and objdump -S and my debugger.

Hope it helps.

NOTE:  For me, I was building a linux kernel.  This change was make in the linux kernel's Makefile.

Comment: I recently encountered an encore of this issue. This time, it was gcc 4.9 vs gdb 7.2. The compiler was generating DWARF v4, while the debugger could only understand up to DWARF v3. Upgrading the debugger resolved it. As a workaround, passing `-gdwarf-3` told it to spit out older format symbol.

Answer (score 3):

Your first point of confusion: `Bar::Baz(Qux*, Quux*)` does *not* imply that debug symbols are present (and in fact implies that they are *not* present).

The debugger merely demangles the function name. If the debug symbols were in fact present, you'd see `Bar::Baz(Qux* qux = 0x12..., Quux* quux = 0x234...)`

As for the real problem, I suspect that the symbol is defined in some *other* library, which

- appears on the link line for the binary before `libfoo.so` does, and
- was built without debug symbols

(The runtime loader will bind the reference to `Bar::Baz()` to the first definition it sees.)

If you print `ip` in frame #7, then do `info symbol <value-just-printed>`, I suspect you'll have an "Aha!" moment.

**EDIT:** Your update made your question self-inconsistent. AFAICT,

1. `gdb` can see debug symbols when you execute
   `libtool --mode=execute gdb .libs/libfoo.so`
2. but not when you execute `libtool    --mode=execute gdb binary`
3. you've verified that the symbol definition is coming from the
   *exact* same `.libs/libfoo.o`
4. and `readelf -w` doesn't see debug symbols in `.libs/libfoo.o`

At least one of the above statements is likely false.

If they are all really true, you probably have a weird `GDB` *and* `readelf` bug (a bug in one is possible, a simultaneous bug in both is somewhat unlikely).

Also note that adding `-g` to `LDFLAGS` is generally the *wrong* thing to do. Did you mean to add it to `CXXFLAGS` instead?

Comment: That's a good point about the name mangling. I'll take a closer look at exactly what's linked in tomorrow morning. I'm doubtful that there's a wrong library involved, since the binary is a test program built in the same tree as the only visible instance of the library that it's supposed to be testing - there are no system installations or anything like that to contend with.

Comment: I just checked this, and the library linked is the library I expect. A typo I made led to an interesting discovery, with which I will amend the original question.

Comment: If you (or anyone else reading this) have other ideas to offer, I'm all ears (eyes, really).

Answer (score 0):

Something made me wonder what the output of `show language` is when you are experiencing
problems.  If its not `c++`, maybe `set language c++` is necessary?